# How to send pdf file back to user using python telegram bot?

Tags: python, pdf, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, sendfile

I tried to use `update.sendDocument(chat_id = update.message.chat_id, document = open(something.pdf, 'b'))` but it did not return me a pdf file. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

For reference, here's a full working example, that worked for me.
If  it still doesnt work, ensure that the pdf docs you send are below 20 MB
as per https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
import telepot
import cookie
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import pdb

def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)
    if content_type == 'text' and msg["text"].lower() == "news":
        # let the human know that the pdf is on its way        
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "preparing pdf of fresh news, pls wait..")
        file="/home/ubuntu/web/news.pdf"

        # send the pdf doc
        bot.sendDocument(chat_id=chat_id, document=open(file, 'rb'))
    elif content_type == 'text':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "sorry, I can only deliver news")

# replace XXXX.. with your token
TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print ('Listening ...')
# Keep the program running.
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Damn... Thanks man. I wonder why author didn't gave you a right answer. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

To send document to user you must have the `file_id` of that document.

Assuming that the user sent the document to `bot` and you want to send back to user, this is my solution:

```
def file_handler (update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    ## retrieve file_id from document sent by user
    fileID = update.message['document']['file_id']
    context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id = chat_id,
                             caption = 'This is the file that you've sent to bot',
                             document = fileID)
```

And on `def main()` you must add:

```
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document, file_handler))
```

With this last line, your `bot` will understand that when user send it a document, and only a document, it will call `def file_handler`.

Comment: OP didn't asked how to handle file form client, he asked how to SEND file to client.

Comment: IMHO, perfectly valid answer. the handling part is for illustration and to make a complete example, together with valid file_id.

Comment: Thank you, Artem!